# Where can I ask about ISO standards?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange site should I use to ask questions about ISO standards?

UPDATE:

What is the ISO name or number used for the following examples?

- fr-fr
- nl-be
- en-us
- en-gb
- etc.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: ISO standards for what?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: So you're looking for a specific ISO standard which defines those language localizations?

Comment: Exactly Bart - I need to know the number and also where to download it.

Comment: @BJJer since you are just looking for a resource, that would be off-topic for any Stack Exchange site.  I think Molot's answer is your best bet

Comment: @BJJer how is standard's ID *not* a resource of a kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your question basically boils down to:

- *Where do I find this canonical reference?* or,
- *What should I be typing into Google to find this canonical reference?*

.. [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) is a great resource. More than a few of our most prolific and *encyclopedic* users frequent the language oriented rooms. This type of question is very easy to answer with just a link and a terse sentence, and usually language agnostic.

If you indicate that you're just having trouble figuring out what to search *for*, and let them know what you've plugged into Google thus far, someone will very likely come to your assistance because we've *all* been there.

The other thing you can do is dig through [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) that relate to the standard you're trying to identify. Look at the 'info' pages for the likely suspects which brings you to the community curated wiki page for that tag. References therein can sometimes lead you to just what you're looking for. Additionally, don't hesitate to suggest and edit to add a link to a useful resource in a tag wiki if it's appropriate.

If you know the standard you're dealing with and you're just having a hard time understanding it, then you've got the makings of a great question.

Answer (score 7):

Most of programming-related ISO standards are pretty well documented on Wikipedia, like [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) that describes country codes or [Language code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code) page that lists standards for them.

Everything about ISO standards, literally, can be found or bought on [www.iso.org](http://www.iso.org).

Comment: If you don't know the exact number, you can look for hours :p

Comment: @BJJer like with everything, really, you either know ID of sort or need to search for it the smart way. You have search on iso.org, search on wikipedia, Google, MSN, and you can search Stack to see who uses these standards in hope they mentioned number.

Comment: P.s. if it's about language codes (and not necessarily just country codes) there is always this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code

Comment: @Bart Imported your link into my post.